# Add a new device in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, xpu

In TensorFlow, a *Session* places the graph ops onto *Devices*, such as *CPU*s or *GPU*s, and provides methods to execute them. Is it possible to add an additional class of devices to TensorFlow? Let's call it XPU in addition to CPU and GPU?

Comment: Hi, did you find a way to add your XPU to TensorFlow ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is possible to add new device types to TensorFlow, although we don't have great documentation. Approximately, it would require adding a new implementation of [`tensorflow::Device`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/device.h), adding a corresponding implementation of [`tensorflow::DeviceFactory`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/device_factory.h), and invoking the following registration macro:

```
REGISTER_LOCAL_DEVICE_FACTORY("XPU", MyXPUDeviceFactory);
```

Comment: Beginnings of such documentation are in this pull request/ https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/4305